# confusion with jquery $.grep

Tags: jquery

I want to display only the name/description pair for where at-least 1 location is a yes(so name3/description 3 pair will not be displayed), i'm trying to use grep but it seems it always returns el and not the array i create within the loop, also temp is empty before return why?,  also it runs return 3 times which probably wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/7zHP3/295/

```
var a, b, c;

a = [
    {
    "name": "name",
    "location1": "no",
    "location2": "no",
    "location3": "yes",
    "location4": "no",
    "location5": "no",
    "description": "description of services"},
{
    "name": "name2",
    "location1": "yes",
    "location2": "no",
    "location3": "yes",
    "location4": "no",
    "location5": "no",
    "description": "description of services2"},
{
    "name": "name3",
    "location1": "no",
    "location2": "no",
    "location3": "no",
    "location4": "no",
    "location5": "no",
    "description": "description of services3"}
];
b = $.grep(a, function(el, i) {
   var temp = [];
  $.each(el, function( index, value ){
  if(index.indexOf("location") != -1 && value == 'yes')
  {
          temp[el.name]= el;

  }

        });
console.log('returning'+temp);
return temp;


});
```

Answer (score 1):

The inner function for grep should return a boolean value. You are trying to return an array.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/

> The function to process each item against. The first argument to the function is the item, and the second argument is the index. The function should return a Boolean value.  `this` will be the global window object.

You want this instead:

```
b = $.grep(a, function(el, i) {
    var found = false;

    $.each(el, function( index, value ){
        found = found || (index.indexOf("location") != -1 && value == 'yes');
    });

    return found;
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6H32h/2/)

Comment: good catch thanks, although what does "|" mean  I've never seen that symbol used before?

Comment: `|=` bitwise OR with assignment